Format and filter ibm-mq queues
I need to display each IBM MQ Queue Manager queue along with its depth.
I can do this with a command like echo DISPLAY QLOCAL(QE*) WHERE(CURDEPTH GE 0) | runmqsc QMNAME.
The output is similar to this:
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2023.
Starting MQSC for queue manager QMNAME.


     1 : DISPLAY QLOCAL(QE*) WHERE(CURDEPTH GE 0)
AMQ8409I: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(QE.QUEUE.NAME1)          TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(2)
AMQ8409I: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(QE.QUEUE.NAME2)          TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(90)
AMQ8409I: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME3)
   TYPE(QLOCAL)                            CURDEPTH(1)
AMQ8409I: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME4)
   TYPE(QLOCAL)                            CURDEPTH(0)
AMQ8409I: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(QE.QUEUE.NAME5)      TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(0)
AMQ8409I: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME6)
   TYPE(QLOCAL)                            CURDEPTH(0)
AMQ8409I: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(QE.QUEUE.NAME7)     TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(0)
One MQSC command read.
No commands have a syntax error.
All valid MQSC commands were processed.


Note that some queues have large names, and the output moves the "TYPE" and "CURDEPTH" fields down and to the right.


My goal is to display these queues as [TYPE] - [QUEUE.NAME] - [DEPTH]:
QLOCAL - QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME3 - 1

So I'm trying to use either sed or awk to accomplish this, and these are some of my attempts:
With awk

awk -F'(QUEUE|TYPE|CURDEPTH)' '/QUEUE\(.*\)/{printf "%s - %s - ", $2, $3}/CURDEPTH/{printf "%s\n", $2}'

$ echo DISPLAY QLOCAL(QE*) WHERE(CURDEPTH GE 0) | runmqsc QMNAME | cat teste | awk -F'(QUEUE|TYPE|CURDEPTH)' '/QUEUE\(.*\)/{printf "%s - %s - ", $2, $3}/CURDEPTH/{printf "%s\n", $2}'
 GE 0)
(QE.QUEUE.NAME1)                - (QLOCAL) - (0)
(QE.QUEUE.NAME2)                - (QLOCAL) - (0)
(QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME3) -  - (QLOCAL)
(QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME4) -  - (QLOCAL)
(QE.QUEUE.NAME5)                - (QLOCAL) - (0)
(QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME6) -  - (QLOCAL)
(QE.QUEUE.NAME7)                - (QLOCAL) - (0)

The main issue is that the output does not display the queue depth correctly when its name is large.

With sed

sed -rn 's|QUEUE\((.*)\)\s+TYPE\((.*)\)\s+CURDEPTH\((\d+)\)|\2 - \1 - \3|p'

$ echo DISPLAY QLOCAL(QE*) WHERE(CURDEPTH GE 0) | runmqsc QMNAME | sed -rn 's|QUEUE\((.*)\)\s+TYPE\((.*)\)\s+CURDEPTH\((\d+)\)|\2 - \1 - \3|p'

$ echo DISPLAY QLOCAL(QE*) WHERE(CURDEPTH GE 0) | runmqsc QMNAME | sed -rn 's|QUEUE\((.*)\)\s+TYPE\((.*)\)|\2 - \1|p'
   QLOCAL - QUEUE.NAME1
   QLOCAL - QUEUE.NAME2
   QLOCAL - QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME3
   QLOCAL - QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME4
   QLOCAL - QE.QUEUE.NAME5
   QLOCAL - QE.QUEUE.NAME.QUEUE.NAME6
   QLOCAL - QE.QUEUE.NAME7

sed shows nothing when I add the \s+CURDEPTH expression. Only when I remove it does it shows the queues, but then I lose the depth value.

Can you guys give me some recommendations on this?

This should work assuming you have GNU grep and awk commands (for example on Linux):
printf "DISPLAY QLOCAL(QE*) WHERE(CURDEPTH GE 0)" | runmqsc QMNAME | grep -o '^\w\+:\|\w\+[(][^)]\+[)]' | awk -F '[()]' 'function printValues() { if ("QUEUE" in p) { printf "%s - %s - %s\n", p["QUEUE"], p["TYPE"], p["CURDEPTH"] } } /^\w+:/ { printValues(); delete p; next } { p[$1] = $2 } END { printValues() }'|column -t
CSV output:
printf "DISPLAY QLOCAL(QE*) WHERE(CURDEPTH GE 0)" | runmqsc QMNAME | grep -o '^\w\+:\|\w\+[(][^)]\+[)]' | awk -F '[()]' -v OFS="," 'function printValues() { if ("QUEUE" in p) { print p["QUEUE"], p["TYPE"], p["CURDEPTH"] } } /^\w+:/ { printValues(); delete p; next } { p[$1] = $2 } END { printValues() }'
